# Is There A List Of What Buddypress Template Files Go Where And What They're To Be Renamed?

Tags: buddypress

If creating a custom wordpress theme that runs buddypress, is there a list of where to put the template files from bp-legacy and what to name them in your theme's buddypress folder?

What I would like to be able to do is allow myself to specify unique templates for BP screens such as 'Groups', 'User', etc. to have better control over how buddypress integrates with my non-standard, customized wordpress themes style and layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This answer is for Buddypress 1.7. No idea how much of it, if any, still applies to the current version (2.8+)*

Here's an as of yet incomplete listing of what files go where. I'll update it as I get more into theming buddypress sites.

The official 'hints' page can be found here..

https://codex.buddypress.org/themes/theme-compatibility-1-7/template-hierarchy/

If you would prefer a basic guide to familiarise you with the template files and how you can make them work for you in your chosen theme you can read this..

https://codex.buddypress.org/themes/theme-compatibility-1-7/a-quick-look-at-1-7-theme-compatibility/

**Note:** There are a couple of templates where the php isn't closed and if you're not using a buddypress.php base template you will need to close them if you're including a wordpress header and footer on those pages.

**Advisory: It's been noted by a buddypress developer that this is not the standard way to customize buddypress to fit with your wordpress theme.** After downvoting (I assume), he failed to provide 'proper' alternatives to this answer.

---

### Profiles

---

**profile -> edit**

from bp-legacy

```
/bp-legacy/buddypress/members/single/profile/edit.php
```

to your theme

```
/yourtheme/buddypress/members/single/index-action-edit.php
```

**profile -> change profile photo**

your.website/members/admin/profile/change-avatar/

```
/bp-legacy/buddypress/members/single/profile/change-avatar.php

/yourtheme/buddypress/members/single/index-action-change-avatar.php
```

**profile -> change cover image**

your.website/members/admin/profile/change-cover-image/

```
/bp-legacy/buddypress/members/single/profile/change-cover-image.php

/yourtheme/buddypress/members/single/index-action-change-cover-image.php
```

**single profile page**

your.website/members/MEMBER-NAME/

```
/bp-legacy/buddypress/members/single/home.php

/yourtheme/buddypress/members/single/index.php
```

---

### Notifications

---

**notifications base template** (notifications.php)

```
/bp-legacy/buddypress/members/single/notifications.php

/yourtheme/buddypress/members/single/index-action-notifications.php
```

will call the loop..

**notifications loop** (notifications-loop.php)

```
/bp-legacy/buddypress/members/single/notifications/notifications-loop.php

/yourtheme/buddypress/members/single/notifications/notifications-loop.php
```

which calls either unread or read..

**notifications -> unread**

your.website/members/admin/notifications/

```
/bp-legacy/buddypress/members/single/notifications/unread.php

/yourtheme/buddypress/members/single/notifications/unread.php
```

**notifications -> read**

your.website/members/admin/notifications/read/

```
/bp-legacy/buddypress/members/single/notifications/read.php

/yourtheme/buddypress/members/single/notifications/read.php
```

or if no notifications exist..

**no notifications** feedback-no-notifications.php

```
/bp-legacy/buddypress/members/single/notifications/feedback-no-notifications.php

/yourtheme/buddypress/members/single/notifications/feedback-no-notifications.php
```

---

### Messages

---

**messages -> inbox** & **messages -> sent**

your.website/members/admin/messages/

your.website/members/admin/messages/sentbox/

*php is unclosed in template file, has to be closed if following this style of theming.

```
/bp-legacy/buddypress/members/single/messages.php

/yourtheme/buddypress/members/single/index-component-messages.php
```

switch - if is inbox or sentbox calls messages-loop.php

**messages loop**

```
/bp-legacy/buddypress/members/single/messages/messages-loop.php

/yourtheme/buddypress/members/single/messages/messages-loop.php
```

calls message.php to view each individual message thread

**message thread**

```
/bp-legacy/buddypress/members/single/messages/message.php

/yourtheme/buddypress/members/single/messages/message.php
```

**messages -> inbox -> 'view message'** the message thread or conversation

```
/bp-legacy/buddypress/members/single/messages/single/single.php

/yourtheme/buddypress/members/single/messages/single.php
```

alternatively you can rename it and place it here (not sure why i had this set up originally)

```
/yourtheme/buddypress/members/single/index-action-view.php
```

**individual message** (from so and so at this time)

called from single message page, single.php/index-action-view.php ..

```
<?php bp_get_template_part( 'members/single/messages/message' ); ?>
```

.

```
/bp-legacy/buddypress/members/single/messages/message.php

/yourtheme/buddypress/members/single/messages/message.php
```

**messages -> starred**

your.website/members/admin/messages/starred/

seems to be the same as inbox.sentbox

**messages -> compose**

called from index-component-messages.php switch case:compose

your.website/members/test-subscriber/messages/compose/

```
/bp-legacy/buddypress/members/single/messages/compose.php

/yourtheme/buddypress/members/single/messages/compose.php
```

**messages -> all member notices** (viewable by admin only)

your.website/members/admin/messages/notices/

calls notices-loop.php

```
<?php bp_get_template_part( 'members/single/messages/notices-loop' ); ?>

needs doing
```

---

### Friends

---

**friends -> friendships**

your.website/members/admin/friends/

*php is unclosed in template file, has to be closed if following this style of theming.

```
/bp-legacy/buddypress/members/single/friends.php

/yourtheme/buddypress/members/single/index-component-friends.php
```

**friends -> pending requests**

your.website/members/admin/friends/requests/

```
/bp-legacy/buddypress/members/single/friends/requests.php

/yourtheme/buddypress/members/single/index-action-requests.php
```

---

### Settings

---

note - there is probably a main template that should call each of these from the original bp-legacy paths. something like a settings.php, ile play around with it and update later.

**settings -> general**

your.website/members/admin/settings/

```
 /bp-legacy/buddypress/members/single/settings/general.php

 /yourtheme/buddypress/members/single/index-action-general.php
```

**settings -> general -> email** (noticiations by email)

your.website/members/admin/settings/notifications/

```
/bp-legacy/buddypress/members/single/settings/notifications.php

/yourtheme/buddypress/members/single/index-action-notifications.php
```

**settings -> general -> profile visibility**

your.website/members/admin/settings/profile/

```
/bp-legacy/buddypress/members/single/settings/profile.php

/yourtheme/buddypress/members/single/index-action-profile.php
```

**settings -> general -> delete account**

*note - you cant see this page as an admin (redirects if u try), its not even listed in the settings menu. log in as a test account (non-admin) to view it.

your.website/members/test-subscriber/settings/delete-account/

```
/bp-legacy/buddypress/members/single/settings/delete-account.php

/yourtheme/buddypress/members/single/index-action-delete-account.php
```